# WPF C# Datagrid update columns from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datagrid

I would like to get data from SQL Management Studio to datagrid but it doesn't work.
First i have a class:

> Person

Where i get the firstName and secondName.

```
class Person
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string secondName { get; set; }

}
```

I already created the button which is designed to make connection to database, use select query and refresh the database.

```
        string dbConnectionString = @"Data Source=Username\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        string sqllogin = "SELECT firstName,secondName FROM TestDatabase.[dbo].[Persons]";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqllogin, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        List<Person> personList;
        personList = new List<Person>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.firstName = reader.GetString(0);
            p.secondName = reader.GetString(1);
            personList.Add(p);
        }

        dataGrid.DataContext = personList;
```

And XAML looks like this:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=firstName}" Header="Name" MinWidth="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=secondtName}" Header="Second Name" MinWidth="100"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

And unfortunately it did not work. Any idea how i can fix this? At this moment when i click the button nothing happens.

Regards.

Comment: Because firstName and secondtName are not properties of a List object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to switch your List into a ObservableCollection and change that

```
dataGrid.DataContext = personList;
```

to

```
dataGrid.ItemSource = personList;
```

Tell me if it's work, and after you can bind the itemsource of the Datagrid to not create a new ObservableCollection, and add directly your "Person".

Comment: Thanks a lot, it work. But at this moment  only first column (firstName) set the data, second column was empty.

Comment: Because the binding the xaml is wrong, you have: `Path=secondtName}"` when it should be: `Path=secondName}"`